# JButtons aren't working?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

For the game i'm making i made a button class to use for all the buttons in my menu. I finally managed to make my buttons appear on screen but now when i click them nothing happens.

my button class:

```
package menu;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Button extends JButton{

    public JButton button;
    public ImageIcon buttonImage;

    public int width, height;

    public String backgroundPath;
    public int x, y;
        public ActionListener listener;



public Button(String backgroundPath,int x, int y, ActionListener listener)

    {
        super();
        this.backgroundPath = backgroundPath;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.addActionListener(listener);   

        buttonImage = new 
            ImageIcon(PlayPanel.class.getResource(backgroundPath));
        button = new JButton();
        this.setIcon(buttonImage);
        this.setBounds(x, y, buttonImage.getIconWidth(), 
            buttonImage.getIconHeight());


    }


}
```

i know there's probably an error in my menupanel (@ actionPerformed). the code looks like this:

```
package menu;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MenuPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{

    private Button playKnop, highScoreKnop, quitKnop, HTPKnop;
    private Tanks mainVenster;
    public MenuPanel menuPanel;

    int x = 95, width = 200, height = 50;



    public MenuPanel(Tanks mainVenster) 
    {
        this.mainVenster = mainVenster;
        this.setLayout(null); 

        playKnop = new Button("/buttons/PLAY.png",x, 350, menuPanel);       
        highScoreKnop = new Button("/buttons/HS.png",x, 460, menuPanel);
        HTPKnop = new Button("/buttons/HTP.png",x, 515, menuPanel);
        quitKnop = new Button("/buttons/QUIT.png",x, 570, menuPanel);


        this.add(playKnop);
        this.add(quitKnop);
        this.add(HTPKnop);
        this.add(highScoreKnop);

        validate();

    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        if (ae.getSource() == playKnop){
        mainVenster.switchPanel(new PlayPanel(mainVenster));

    } else if (ae.getSource() == quitKnop) {
        mainVenster.switchPanel(new QuitPanel(mainVenster));

    } else if (ae.getSource() == HTPKnop) {
        mainVenster.switchPanel(new HTPPanel(mainVenster));

    } else if (ae.getSource() == highScoreKnop) {
        mainVenster.switchPanel(new HSPanel(mainVenster));
    }

    }

}
```

i think the error is the fact that i'm writing mainVenster (venster = dutch for panel/window) and i should probably write other parameters. the problem is that i don't know which ones.

Comment: Careful -- you're painting yourself in a corner by using null layouts. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your buttons in the listener, so you must refer to class itself as `this`:

```
playKnop = new Button("/buttons/PLAY.png",x, 350, this);       
highScoreKnop = new Button("/buttons/HS.png",x, 460, this);
HTPKnop = new Button("/buttons/HTP.png",x, 515, this);
quitKnop = new Button("/buttons/QUIT.png",x, 570, this);
```

You already have a `menuPanel` attribute, so when creating the class you can assign a value, in this case `this`.

```
menuPanel = this;
```

But I wont recommend you delete this attribute or rename it to `_this` or `_menuPanel` to agree conventions.

Comment: right right right, omg can't believe i didn't come up with that myself! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is a `java.awt.Button` class. I would consider not calling your new button class `Button` in order to prevent any namespace confusion.

You need to pass in `this` instead of `menuPanel` as `ActionListener`s for your buttons:

```
playKnop = new Button("/buttons/PLAY.png",x, 350, this);
```